# Possible optimization of going through pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find a way to optimize looping through pandas dataframe. The dataset contains ~450k rows with ~20 columns. The dataframe contains 3 locational variables as multiindex and I want to drop the rows where NaN columns exist within the group, otherwise fill NaN with mean of the group.

```
LOC = ['market_id', 'midmarket_id', 'submarket_id']

# Assign -1000 to multiindex nan values
df = df.fillna({c:-1000 for c in LOC})
df = df.set_index(LOC).sort_index(level=[i for i in range(len(LOC))])

# Looping through subset with same (market, midmarket, submarket)
for k, v in df.copy().groupby(level=[i for i in range(len(LOC))]):

    # If there is any column with all NaN value, drop it from df
    if v.isnull().all().any():
        df.drop(v.index.values)

    # If there is at least one non-NaN value, fillna with mean
    else:
        df.loc[v.index.values] = df.loc[v.index.values].fillna(v.mean())
```

So if there is dataframe like this
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k17N.png)
and it should be converted like this, removing the rows with all NaN columns
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyeIk.png).

I apologize if this is redundant or not accordance with stack overflow question guideline. But if anyone has better solution for this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to copy your entire dataframe. Nor is there a need to iterate `GroupBy` elements manually. Here's an alternative solution:

```
LOC = ['market_id', 'midmarket_id', 'submarket_id']

# Assign -1000 to NaN values
df = df.fillna(-1000)

# Include only columns containing non-nulls
non_nulls = np.where(df.notnull().any())[0]
df = df.iloc[:, non_nulls]

# Fill columns with respective groupwise means
g = df.groupby(LOC)

for col in df.columns.difference(LOC):
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(g[col].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: It seems line 3-7 is not really doing anything. All NaN is filled with -1000 on line 3 so there is nothing happening afterward. However, I applied the last two lines of your code replacing the for loop and solved my problem. Thank you!